# Snowflake Integration Options without ELT

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

what are the options for the snowflake integration without the need for ELT tools?
my input would be CSV, JSON, or data directly from API.

Comment: This question is too open ended. Do you have more specifics?

Comment: so i  need to load 50 to 100 tables in snowflake on a daily basis without any ETL tool.

Comment: did you check the docs? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html (anything unclear?)

Comment: i did  but we need to have merge here insert/update , not just loading